# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Nativemodules.UIManager.RCTVideo.Constants')

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I am trying to use a video player for React Native, and came across this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video#todos

I ran npm install react-native-video 
 
react-native link

```
import Video from "react-native-video";
class Topics extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Video source={{ uri: './videos/asthma-1.mp4' }} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: have you try to follow the instruction to setting the android or iOs ?

Comment: try using this `source={require('./videos/asthma-1.mp4')}`

Comment: @RizalSidik Not sure about any instructions, I just ran the code that I wrote in my question, which  I found on another stack overflow. Are there android instructions you can tell me about?

Comment: i mean like setting the `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` in android folder, have you already follow that instruction ?

Comment: No, I noticed that in the docs for react-native-video (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video), but I don't have an android folder. I'm using the create-react-native-app command for my project

Answer (score 0):

Run the command of **react-native link** and after **react-native run-android**.

The first command links the dependencies and after that it will work!